# How to add Android.Dialogs inside scrollable fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, scrollview

I am developing the Android version of my Xamarin.iOS application, so I want to share as much code as possible between both platforms.

I am using `MonoTouch.Dialog` for iOS screens and the MvvmCross `Android.Dialog` for Android screens.

How would be the best approach to develop the right side (Android) screen?

[image: iOSToAndroidDialogScreens]

I am targeting `Android 4.0.3+` and using the `Support Library v13 (Rev 18)` to work with child fragments.

The [DialogListFragment](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/fffe39c9e3a9eae24e55fdf58cf6f84d71a4654d/CrossUI/CrossUI.Droid/Dialog/DialogListFragment.cs) is a custom Android ListFragment.

I have been reading lots of questions about ListViews embedded inside a ScrollView but I could not figure it out yet what is the best practice to follow. Is there some official documentation?

When trying to implement the right (Android) screen I could see two behaviours:

- By using the internal `ScrollView`, all child fragments' `ListViews` are displaying just their first content row;
- By eliminating the internal `ScrollView`, fragments get correctly displayed. But in some cases, their height may be higher then the screen height and so they will not completely appear.

Comment: *I have been reading lots of questions about ListViews embedded inside a ScrollView but I could not figure it out yet what is the best practice to follow* - the best practice is to not put scrollable widgets like `ListViews` in other scrollable containers like a `ScrollView`. *But the latest fragment gets cut by the end of the view.* - what exactly does this mean?

Comment: Hi @Luksprog `But the latest fragment gets cut by the end of the view` means that if the last internal fragment has a bigger height than the device screen height for example, it will not completely appear. This is why I need an ScrollView.

Comment: I've just found a workaround (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3495908/699915) developed by @DougW. I will be using it until changing the way my screens are being created.